# Images in the carousel keep changing the size. It must not change size from image to image

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have tried changing height and width without any luck.

The carousel is made with bootstrap.

JQuery is used. I guess the issue is with CSS and html.

I have tried to fix the issue by changing height and width values.

The images must not change height. The height keeps on changing from image to image.

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- resorts card container--->



  <div class="row justify-content-left my-5">
    <!-- row for carousel pb5 means bottom padding--->
    <div class=" mycarousel col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-8">
      <!-- carousel column begins--->
      <div id="carousel" data-interval="5000" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>


        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner w-100 h-50">
          <div class="carousel-item active">

            <img class="d-block" src="images/resorts/banyan_tree_vabbinfaru/banyan_tree_vabbinfaru_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>


          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block" src="images/resorts/banyan_tree_vabbinfaru/banyan_tree_vabbinfaru_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>



        </div>
        <!-- carousel div close--->

      </div>
      <!-- carousel column close--->
```